# Meaning of intrinsic type with () in C++

Tags: c++

What does it mean when an intrinsic type has the parenthesis operators with it.

e.g. *int*() or *float*()

Is it like a default constructor or does it have a different meaning for intrinsic types?

----edit----

To add more context:

In my school textbook for C++, I am on a chapter about Templates. A template being used for demonstration is a **Table** template (a 2D array). One of the functions for **Table** is a *resize* method to change the dimensions of the table and is also used in some constructors used for **Table**. The constructor in question and the *resize* method are:

```
template <typename T> 
Table<T>::Table<T>(int m, int n) 
{  
    mDataMatrix = 0;  
    mNumRows    = 0;  
    mNumCols    = 0;  
    resize(m, n, T()); 
}
```

and

```
template <typename T> 
void Table<T>::resize(int m, int n, const T& value) 
{  
    // Destroy the previous data.
    destroy();   

    // Save dimensions.  
    mNumRows = m;  
    mNumCols = n;   

    // Allocate a row (array) of pointers.  
    mDataMatrix = new T*[mNumRows];   

    // Now, loop through each pointer in this row array.  
    for(int i = 0; i < mNumRows; ++i)  
    {   
        // And allocate a column (array) to build the table.   
        mDataMatrix[i] = new T[mNumCols];    

        // Now loop through each element in this row[i]   
        // and copy 'value' into it.   
        for(int j = 0; j < mNumCols; ++j)    
            mDataMatrix[i][j] = value;  
    } 
}
```

In the constructor definition, *resize*'s third argument is *T*() (and I assume *T* becomes whatever the specified type for the template is).

In the definition for *resize*, *T*() is used for the *value* argument to assign a default value to the elements in the table.

From some of the earlier answers, this is zero-initialization. I assume that means the value is 0 for each element in the table (or some equivalent of 0 if the type is a *string*, I guess). Is this correct?

Comment: It should be a default (zero-initializing) "constructor", but some code with an example of this usage would be preferable

Comment: Short C++ fragments can have many meanings depending on context. Please show a meaningful excerpt from a working program.

Comment: This particular construct has at least two distinct meanings, depending on context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is [value initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization).

e.g. `auto x = int();` means `int x = 0`

In the example provided `T()` will create an object of type `T` and pass it as a parameter.

You could also write:

```
resize(m, n, T{});
```

Answer (score 3):

Acutally, your code does something different than when you're declaring just a `int` or a `float`. It zero initialize the numbers.

example, those three lines are equivalent:

```
int a = int();

int a = int{};

int a{};
```

All those three are zero initialized.